# Matching json array from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i have a column in my users database called "tags" which could look like this:

```
`[1,2,3,4]`
```

That array only has numbers.

I am now wondering if I can select from the database where the *json array* has specific value in it. For example:

```
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE tags = "HAS 1 IN ARRAY"`
```

I was testing by just matching the number 1 but then it will probably return values with 10 to 19 if any user has number 10-19 in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]';
```

For more info, see docs [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

PS I would recommend to decompose table, move tags into dependent table. On large table regexp will be slow...